# MySQL : "Appending more data to a column"

Tags: mysql, database

Is it possible to append a string to an existing data on a MySQL table?

For instance the Column "Interest" already has "Fishing"; and I would like to add "Travelling" so that it would end up becoming "Fishing , Travelling".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `CONCAT`

`UPDATE table SET field_name = CONCAT(field_name,’, string_to_add’) WHERE id=’1’;`